# Split a string on sqlite

Tags: string, sqlite, coronasdk

i don't know sqlite but I have to implement a database already done. I'm programming with Corona SDK. The problem: i have a column called "answers" in this format: `House,40|Bed,20|Mirror,10` ecc.
I want to split the string and remove `"," "|"` like this:

```
VARIABLE A=House

VARIABLE A1=40


VARIABLE B=Bed

VARIABLE B1=20

VARIABLE C=Mirror

VARIABLE C1=10
```

I'm sorry for my english. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: you could fetch each row's value and split it using the split function in java.

Comment: Corona SDK is based on Lua language

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the info. i wasnt aware of that, i was under the concept that corona sdk can be part of android, so it suports java :).. thanks ..

Comment: You're welcome :) so, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: No there's no other option, i believe sqlite doesnot provide such a function , you will have to handle it in lua language itself. Sql too doesnt provide this, although there is a substr and a concate function

Comment: I understand..I hope someone could help me, thanks

Comment: keep googling till someone who has faced this issue answers you :).. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

If you want to simply remove the characters, then you can use the following:

**Update 3 :**

```
local myString = "House;home;flat,40|Bed;bunk,20|Mirror,10"
local myTable = {}
local tempTable = {}

local count_1 = 0
for word in string.gmatch(myString, "([^,|]+)") do
    myTable[#myTable+1]=word
    count_1=count_1+1
    tempTable[count_1] = {} -- Multi Dimensional Array
    local count_2 = 0
    for word_ in string.gmatch(myTable[#myTable], "([^,|,;]+)") do
        count_2=count_2+1
        local str_ = word_
        tempTable[count_1][count_2] = str_
        --print(count_1.."|"..count_2.."|"..str_)
    end
end

print("------------------------")
local myTable = {} -- Resetting my table, just for using it again :)
for i=1,count_1 do
    for j=1,#tempTable[i] do
        print("tempTable["..i.."]["..j.."] = "..tempTable[i][j])
        if(j==1)then myTable[i] = tempTable[i][j] end
    end
end

print("------------------------")
for i=1,#myTable do
    print("myTable["..i.."] = "..myTable[i])
end
--[[ So now you will have a multidimensional array tempTable with
     elements as:
        tempTable = {{House,home,flat},
                     {40},
                     {Bed,bunk},
                     {20},
                     {Mirror},
                     {10}}

     So you can simply take any random/desired value from each.
     I am taking any of the 3 from the string "House,home,flat" and
     assigning it to var1 below:
--]]

var1 = tempTable[1][math.random(3)]
print("var1 ="..var1)

-- So, as per your need, you can check var1 as: 
for i=1,#tempTable[1] do  -- #tempTable[1] means the count of array 'tempTable[1]'
  if(var1==tempTable[1][i])then
    print("Ok")
    break;
  end
end

----------------------------------------------------------------
   -- Here you can print myTable(if needed) --
----------------------------------------------------------------
for i=1,#myTable do
  print("myTable["..i.."]="..myTable[i])
end

--[[ The output is as follows:
    myTable[1]=House
    myTable[2]=40
    myTable[3]=Bed
    myTable[4]=20
    myTable[5]=Mirror
    myTable[6]=10

    Is it is what you are looking for..?
 ]]--

 ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Keep coding............. :)

Comment: And if i want to insert the words in some specific variables? for example: varA=House, varA1=40, varB=Bed ecc? The maximun number of variables i have is seven for the words and seven for the numbers(
existing variables).

Comment: @Nick21Android: You can assign it as: varA=myTable[1]; varA1=myTable[2]; and so on...

Comment: Yes it was so easy, sorry!!
I ask you the last problem: sometimes i have synonyms, for example House;home,40|Bed,20|Mirror,10 (separated by ";")but not always, so i can't assign the exact number of item at a specific variable. For example in this case myTable[2] is "home", not more a number. Do you have some ideas?
The variables must print only the first word (House) but i need to keep memory the second, or third (ecc) word as in this case "home"
Sorry for my english

Comment: Wow it works great! It was still difficult for me :)
Now i should be able to set all, thank you so much!
I ask you another little thing (forgive me): how can i concatenate a table item with text? For example bt.text = (myTable[2]**here i want to add " %"**)
With .. doesn't work

Comment: The concatenation will work. I've included that also in the above updated code..... :)

Comment: Yes you're right! The error has been occurring when the table doesn't exist so i thought it was the concatenation, sorry :)

Comment: Hi @krs, I thought it was all right, but now during the tests an error has occured. The tempTable doesn't save the second or third (etc.) choises of the same table.
Example:
local myString = "House;home;flat,40|Bed;bunk,20|Mirror,10"
***Other code***

--I want to do this:

if var1==myTable[1] or var1=="home" or var1=="flat" then
print("Ok")
end

How can I do this with "home" and "flat"? And if the choises are three or four? And if there isn't a second choise?

Comment: @Nick21Android: Hi friend, I've updated the code for your need. Keep coding.......... :)

Comment: Hey @krs, you are the best! Thank you for all the time you have spent to teach me this!!
I ask you the last thing (I hope!!):
if var1 == tempTable[3][?] then print("ok") end
what do I have to replace "?" with? So I doesn't have to write tempTable[3][2], tempTable[3][3] etc., even because the number of second choises changes every time.

Comment: @Nick21Android: Ok, I'm usually doing it with a for loop with limit as the count of the specific array. I've updated the code............ :)

Comment: thanks it's ok!! But now I can't use ex: myTable[1] around the "app" as first, I must find the error.
Thank you for everything!

Comment: Oh sorry, I've replaced the old code for updating. But now, instead of your old 'myTable[1]',I think, you can use 'tempTable[1][1]'. If you still find a problem with that, then feel free to inform. We will surely help you from our maximum........ :)

Comment: If I replace for example 'myTable[1]' with 'tempTable[1][1]' it give me an error when it doesn't exist

Comment: I have updated the code. But now I am confused about your exact need. If you get time, pleas update the question too.... :) And keep coding............. :)

Comment: My app is a quiz, at the first manche the answers are 7 so the code arrives up to "myTable[13]"(for the words) and "myTable[14]"(for the number). The second manche there are 6 answers, the third manche 5 answers etc. If I use tempTable[1][1], ....., tempTable[13][1] for example at the second manche it gives me an error: the tempTable[13][1] doesn't exist, of course.
Before the update (before multidimensional array etc.) when i used myTable[13] it didn't give me any error even if the answer didn't exist. How can I resolve? Have you understand?

Comment: I noticed this:
if it's the second manche "myTable[13]" takes the value of "myTable[1]". If it's the third manche "myTable[11]" takes the value of "myTable[1]" and "myTable[13]" takes the value of "myTable[3]", etc.

Comment: No, the table value should be "nil", not the repetition of the first tables

Comment: As I said earlier, I'm a little bit confused about the question. I'll tell you your need. Just read it and tell me am I right about the question.`myString = "House;home;flat,40|Bed;bunk,20|Mirror,10"` . You need to split the string with `;` `,` and `|`. Your have to assign anyone from `House;home;flat` to myTable[1]. And myTable[2] has to be its value (that is `40`). Right? That you can surely get from the answer. Then what else is needed, pls clarify, I'm totally confused now.   If possible, please update your need in the question above, so I can clarify. :)

Comment: Have you read the comment where I try to explain my app? :)
This is the video of the app that I'm doing for Android: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCTcY3GUj6M
Have you understood what is my problem? :)

Comment: Sorry, I cant able to understand the language. :D. Can u please edit the question at the top of this page with further needs...?